# K Means Clustering Algorithm Difficulty in 3+ Clusters

Tags: java, k-means

Currently, I am auto-generating clusters of data in Java then attempting to use K Means clustering to find their centers. The K Means algorithm that I use involves creating k cluster seed locations by setting each cluster seed location as the location of a data point, assigning each data point to the nearest cluster, readjusting the cluster location based on the average of all the x and y coordinates of data points assigned to that cluster, and then continuing this cycle until their is no movement in the cluster locations.

This algorithm works very effectively with less than or equal to 3 clusters as illustrated in the scatter plot below where orange circles represent cluster locations and blue circles represent data points.
[image]

However, as I add more than 3 data points, the algorithm falls apart as I encounter different scenarios. This issue is illustrated in the graph below:
[image]

Although this appears to be a flaw in the code, if you consider the plausibility of the results, it is certainly a correct execution of the aforementioned algorithm, as the locations of the different clusters enable these results  Is this issue a result of the limitations of the K Means algorithm, or is there a way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using more cluster centres (5 instead of 3 in the example above)?

Comment: If you look closely, 3 of the cluster centers are located on the bottom left cluster of data.

Comment: Essentially, these 3 clusters are all assigned to different data points in this cluster of data, while the rightmost cluster center is assigned to the rightmost data clusters, and the leftmost cluster center is assigned to the leftmost data points since they are the closest. This error originates from the initial seeding of the clusters, but I'm stumped at how to fix this.

Comment: Ahh. This is an inherent potential problem with k means and is to do with initial conditions. You can try setting the starting locations to a random close centre point between all data. There are other ways you can fix this problem by extending k means though. Make a js version in a fiddle or something and i could show some options.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I presumed. I'll try adjusting the seed position like you mentioned. As for Fiddle, I'll try that as well.

Comment: This might be worth looking at too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_gas